# jq select based on two conditions within one child object

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json file with the following format

```
{"id": "3DFD4GF", "demographic": [{"country": "Spain", "rating": 7},{"country": "Germany", "rating": 2}]}
```

I want to see each line where `country` is "Canada" and `rating` is 10 in the same object within the `demographic` array

I tried:
`jq 'select((.demographic[].country=="Canada") and .demographic[].rating==10)' json`

but this will return lines where inside the `demographic` array there can be any object containing `"country": "Canada"` and any object where `"rating": 10`

However, my goal is to have those two key value pairs in the **same** object

The expected output is:

`{"id": "454FGF6", "demographic": [{"country": "Germany", "rating": 4},{"country": "Canada", "rating": 10}]}`

How can I change my query to return the desired result?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output (format) – array, stream, single object, …?

Comment: The expected output is to be able to see the entire line where the condition is met, eg. {"id": "454FGF6", "demographic": [{"country": "Germany", "rating": 4},{"country": "Canada", "rating": 10}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)) to check if *any* of the `demographic` match your logic:

```
select(.demographic | any(.country == "Spain" and .rating == 7))
```

```json
{
  "id": "3DFD4GF",
  "demographic": [
    {
      "country": "Spain",
      "rating": 7
    },
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "rating": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4k86AVC4G5S)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to see the entire line and not just the object within demographic